# Create HVM EC2 from PV EC2 using aws console

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have m3.medium server on amazon and i want to change it to t2.medium but it's on PV virtualization. So can't just change instance type. But i have an idea to solve this. Here is the step:

1. Creating new hvm t2.medium instance
2. Stop m3.medium server and detach volume
3. Attach volume to newly created hvm
4. Terminate m3.medium

But there is some question before i did it.

- There is plenty of alarms assigned pv server. How to keep that?
- Is there a way to do it by keep everything?
- Is there anything i forget? What i mean is do i lose something else or are there anything else i have to configure again?

Answer (score 0):

You'll also lose everything on the m3.medium's instance-store volume, unless you copy it to an EBS volume first.